# Antimatter Generation With The Help Of A Plasma Globe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electricity, radiation, antimatter

I know this sounds absurd, but after doing a little research I found that it may be possible (not entirely, but that is why I am asking about this here). I have been reading up on antimatter and quantum mechanics and I stumbled across [this](https://phys.org/news/2017-11-lightning-chance-antimatter.html) article on the subject of "creating antimatter with lightning". All lightning is is a stream of electrons travelling through a channel of ionised air. This is true of any electrical "arc". This brings me to my question. There is a trick which you can do with plasma globes (you can probably pick one up at a toy store quite easily), where you place  a piece of aluminium foil on the top of the globe which attracts a stream of electrons via parasitic capacitance the the environment. However, I have put together a specialised spark-gap chamber which consists of two metal rods with sharp points ~0.2mm apart so that an arc jumps the gap. I attached a wire from the aluminium foil on the plasma globe to one of the electrodes, and I connected the other to ground. When I switched on the plasma globe, as expected, a small arc jumped the gap.

This experiment, while much less powerful (about 900,000 times less powerful) than lightning, does simulate it to some degree (with a constant flow of electrons with AC current instead of a small pulse of electrons with pulse current).

#### So if lightning can emit antiprotons and positrons, can my setup do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Lightning producing postitrons, i.e. the antiparticle of the electron [can be seen here](https://phys.org/news/2017-11-lightning-chance-antimatter.html)

> In a collaborative study appearing in Nature, researchers from Japan describe how gamma rays from lightning react with the air to produce radioisotopes and even positrons—the antimatter equivalent of electrons.

....

> The gamma rays emitted in lightning have enough energy to knock a neutron out of atmospheric nitrogen,

....

> The final, prolonged emission was from the breakdown of now neutron-poor and unstable nitrogen atoms. These released positrons, which subsequently collided with electrons in annihilation events releasing gamma rays.

So it is not exactly pair creation. The energy of a lightning bolt is very large and gammas produced in order to create pairs of electron positrons would have to be at least 1MeV in energy.

The sparks in [a spark gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_gap) in the lab do not have enough energy to generate gamma rays.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help. Have you got any ideas on how I could create 1MeV of energy (sorry if it's a silly question)? EDIT: 1MeV seems quite small, because my desktop lamp can output up to 3.745x10^20 eV (60W bulb), are you sure my spark gap cannot output 1MeV?

Comment: @sciencepiofficial One million volts is *not* "quite small"! You can make high voltage in various ways, eg a [Tesla coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil). But please be careful. As well as the hazards of high voltage, you need to make sure you aren't exposing yourself to unhealthy amounts of X-rays / gamma rays.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thankyou for your concern, very much appreciated, however, in your answer you wrote `1 MeV` (megaelectronvolt) not `1 Mv` (megavolt). I will be sure to construct a lead container to do these experiments in future. Also, I have a tesla coil, but its just a slayer exciter sadly, and the impedance of the wire loads the voltage significantly. Perhaps I could attempt a van de graaf machine. Thanks again for your help, best wishes.

Comment: @sciencepiofficial Um, that's not my answer, it's Anna V's. Yes, there's a difference between volts & electron-volts. But for this application (creating gamma rays powerful enough to cause nuclear reactions), you *do* need high voltage.

Comment: Sorry, honest mistake, you are correct, I will take a look into various ways of creating high voltage. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: An electron volt is just the energy it takes to move an electron through a potential difference of 1 volt. To give an electron 1 MeV of energy you must have a pd of 1 million volts.

Comment: @sciencepiofficial  the energy of a bit higher than 1 MeV has to be the energy of one gamma-ray/photon in order to have electron positron creation . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production  .The wats of your lamp are distributed among zillions of photons, because light emerges from the superposition of them.

Comment: The [*Nature* article](https://www.nature.com/news/lightning-makes-new-isotopes-1.23033) has a little more detail. The [Nitrogen-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen-13) is created by gammas with energy around 10 MeV. (The usual way of making N-13 with a cyclotron involves slamming 5.55 MeV protons into O-16, which yields N-13 + an $\alpha$ particle). N-13 decays by $\beta^+$ emission, with a half-life just under 10 minutes, and a decay energy of 1.2 MeV.